# При заполнении поля требует выбора другого поля

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите, как можно написать условие делающее следующее.

При заполнении (печатании) любыми символами `surname и name` требует чтобы сначала выбрали в `conid`.

```html
<select id="conid" name="conId" onchange="conIdchange()">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
  <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
</select>
<input id="surname" name="surname" class="css-input" type="text" value="">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Чтобы прям не давало вводить пока не выбрано поле conid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант **Air**'а хорош, но даёт слабину, так сказать:
[image: "Автозаполнение" работает]

---

**UPD**:

Изначально выставите "запрещённым" инпутам атрибут `disabled="disabled"`

```js
$('#conid').bind('change', function(){
  var selectVal = $(this).val();
  $('#surname, #name').prop('disabled', selectVal == 0 ? true : false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="conid" name="conId">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
  <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
</select>
<input id="surname" name="surname" class="css-input" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Мне на какой объект можно нацепить чтобы работало? Просто у меня много скриптов и функций которые могут помешать сделать этот скрипт.

Comment: @wq55, если вёрстка не изменена, то код заработает.

Comment: Спасибо. Будут искать место куда его внедрить чтобы заработал.

Answer (score 1):

Как пример

```js
$('#surname,#name').on('input', function() {
  if ($('#conid').val() == '0') {
    $(this).val('');
    console.log('Выберите conId');
    return false;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="conid" name="conId">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
  <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
</select>

<input id="surname" name="surname" class="css-input" type="text" value="">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Чтобы вводить не давало символы в поля surname и name или их заблокировать пока поле conid не выбрано можно?

Comment: @wq55 ну так и есть в примере )) вы смотрели пример в работе? разве можете заполнить поле если не выбран что то из conId?

Answer (score 0):

Запретить можно по разному. Например атрибут `disabled`

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(s => {

  // Прокручиваем все INPUT в цикле и проверяем если INPUT в фокусе,

  s.addEventListener('focus', () => {

    // а у SELECT ничего не выбрано блокируем INPUT

    if (document.querySelector('#conid').value == '0') {

      s.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    // а если выбран SELECT разблокируем INPUT
    document.querySelector('#conid').addEventListener('change', () => {
      s.removeAttribute("disabled")
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="conid" name="conId">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
  <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
</select>

<input id="surname" name="surname" class="css-input" type="text" value="">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Пока проверил на https://jsfiddle.net Да работает. Буду пробовать в программе. Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Comment: Что-то у меня дают ошибки.